Can a valid linked solution to a question still be considered spam?
This answer to an older question is at the moment in the "first answers" queue:

You're not the first, and you certainly won't be the last to explore
this area. Nowadays, there are plenty of tools available for
extracting data from graphs. Recently, my choice has fallen on
https://splinecloud.com/features/plot-digitizing/. It's a convenient
and user-friendly tool that, in some aspects, even surpasses its
competitors. I hope you'll find it helpful as well.

I am reluctant to mark it as "ok", as I find it borderline spammy. There are other answers that link to other solutions as well, but the phrasing of this answer feels off to me - it reads more like an advert than a genuine recommendation. Nevertheless, I had a look and the linked service seems to offer a solution to what OP was looking for in their question.
So my question (as per the title): can a valid link-answer still be considered spam?

FWIW, I also saw the answer and considered it spammy enough to do some basic spam checks (prominently whether the author is advertising their own product).


can a valid link-answer still be considered spam?

Yes, absolutely. Most notably if a user is associated with a company but does not disclose that association when recommending that company's products. Or if most/all of a user's posts are promoting a company's products, even with disclosure. When in doubt, it's best to flag such things; mods have a few extra tools we can use to investigate.
As for this post, I am not sure whether it is spam, but it is definitely not an answer. OP is asking for advice on how to get the paper authors to provide the exact values. Inferring the approximate values from the graph is not of interest (and even if it were, I strongly doubt that using third-party plot digitization software is necessary; reading a graph is something that any high school algebra student should be able to do).

FWIW The currently highest scored answer also recommends a tool for data extraction. It also offers some commentary on details, but doesn’t seem to address the question itself any more thoroughly.

Well, the last sentence of that answer is arguably an answer to the actual question. I agree that part of the answer should be expanded upon, but that user insists on writing in a very concise style.

@cag51 I've actually extracted a bunch of values from plots recently for a power analysis. If you're looking at scatterplots, extracting values from the graph is pretty straightforward.

Of course it is; as I said, any high school algebra student should be able to do it. But inferring from the graph is not equivalent to having the actual values from which the graph was made. It's as if I asked for the exact time something happened, down to four decimal places, and someone "answered" by assuming I didn't know how to read an analog clock and recommending software to do it for me.

Note that what is spam and what is not is a judgment call by users and mods. It isn't precisely defined. In particular, some things are marked as spam when the writer does, in fact, disclose their relationship either in the post or in their profile. So, disclosure is not the whole story.
The judgement comes in from an analysis of the post itself. What does it contribute beyond a recommendation of a product. If an answer points to a product and does, in fact, provide a useful answer to the question (or if a question provides a valid question), then it might not be considered spam.
But if the post simply says "look at this product and you will find an answer" then it might be considered spam. That is the case, I think, even when the writer has no link to the product. That is to say, it might be considered spam, not that it will be. Judgement of the community is needed.
To be honest, I find the guidance on spam to be less than completely useful. There may be too much leeway in the guidance for the judgement to be correct. I think it mostly works, and have marked many posts as spam. But other factors in a post can influence voting, including what I've seen as prejudicial comments.
